# TypeError: this.props.navigation.getParam is not a function while passing parameter using ReactNative

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am getting an error while accessing parameter by the getParam method like following
.

```
    const source = this.props.navigation.getParam("source","0")
    const doFollow = this.props.navigation.getParam("doFollow","")
```

I have passed the parameter using the following method

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Details', {otherParam:"anything"})
```

Comment: Can you add some more details please ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It depends on your `react-navigation` version that you are using.

In v4

```
this.props.navigation.getParam('source')
```

In v5

```
this.props.route.params.source
```

Answer (score 1):

It may not fit your example completely but i'm passing/retrieving data like this:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('DisplayPage', { meetId: item.ID })
```

Then on receiving page

```
props.navigation.state.params.meetId
```

Answer (score 1):

If You are using the latest version of react navigation(i.e. Version 5.0 or more). You can simply use `this.props.route.params.YOUR_PARAMETER_KEY` for passing parameters

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send data(ex. JSON) from one class to another in React-Native.

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Detail Screen', json)
```

Here json is the JSON object with key-value. Ex.

```
    { id: 1234, name: "Dean", age: 30}
```

In the receiver class/ Navigated Class in render

```
     const name = this.props.route.params.name;
     const age = this.props.route.params.age;
```

NOTE:Please make sure data is send as key value {key: value}

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using the latest `react-navigation`.
You are making a small mistake.

Try removing the second parameter from the function.

```
let source = this.props.navigation.getParam("source")
let doFollow = this.props.navigation.getParam("doFollow")

if(!source) source = "0"
if(!doFollow) doFollow = ""
```

Comment: I have tried this and the error still persists, do you know any another method to pass parameters between class components.

Comment: Can you add some code and details like what is the version you are using?

Answer (score 0):

```
props.navigation.getParams(**source**) is not working in V4

props.route.params.**source** in at V5
```

V5:

without object destructuring -->

```
function(props)
{
   props.navigation.goBack() //For navigation
   props.route.params.**source** //For params
}
```

with object destructuring -->

```
function({navigation, route})
{
   navigation.goBack()    //FOR navigation
   route.params.**source**   //FOR params
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but why have you added this answer? Do you want to point anything? Could you elaborate on your point?

Comment: Yes, the point is... getParams does not get any parameter in V5.    props.route.params.source      not getParams().