# How to print news detail in react native?

Tags: react-native

In my file `AppNavigator.js` already added the `Detail.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import Splash from '../screens/Splash';
import TabNavigator from './NewsList';
import Details from './Detail';

const AppStack = createStackNavigator();

export default function AppNavigator() {
    return(
        <AppStack.Navigator>
            <AppStack.Screen name="Splash" component={Splash} options={{headerShown:false}}/>
            <AppStack.Screen name="Root" component={TabNavigator} options={{headerShown:false}} />
            <AppStack.Screen name="Details" component={Details} options={{headerShown:false}} />
        </AppStack.Navigator>
    );
}
```

In my `NewsList.js` ([code complete](https://jsfiddle.net/qdfns57r/)) file where I list all the news, I have the following parameter where information is intended to be retrieved when clicking on any news:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate("Details",{news:item})}>
```

The problem that I present in the file `Detail.js` where I can not get the information of the news to print all the information of the news:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Dimensions,
  FlatList,
  Image,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  ImageBackground
} from 'react-native';

//const navigation = useNavigation();
//const route = useRoute();
//const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;

var {height, width } = Dimensions.get('window');
const baseUrl = "https://spektand.com/restapijson.php?key=bc989b8b068828fbefcea26e55160a3fe79cacaf067e874c531ad193d06c2d9b"

//this.props.route.params.source v5
//this.props.navigation.getParam('source') v4
export default class Details extends React.Component {
    render(){
        const data = this.props.navigation.getParam('news')
        return(
            <View style={{flex:1}}>
                <Text>Screen Details {JSON.stringify(data)} </Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

When I press it prints the following error:

> `ERROR  TypeError: this.props.navigation.getParam is not a function. (In 'this.props.navigation.getParam('news')', 'this.props.navigation.getParam' is undefined)`

Can you explain to me what I am doing wrong? information of the versions that I am using in my application:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.9",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.1.8",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.11",
    "@types/react-native-swiper": "^1.5.12",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "link": "^0.1.5",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "^0.66.4",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
    "react-native-countdown-component": "^2.7.1",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-pager-view": "^5.4.9",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.2.4",
    "react-native-redux": "^1.0.11",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.10.1",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.0.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
    "superagent": "^6.1.0"
  }
```

I have already checked some sources, I have tried the following https://jsfiddle.net/Lb01t9gc/ but nothing I manage to get it to work.

- https://reactnavigation.org/docs/2.x/navigation-prop/
- https://reactnavigation.org/docs/2.x/params/
- https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/
- https://snack.expo.dev/
- [TypeError: this.props.navigation.getParam is not a function while passing parameter using ReactNative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61126610/typeerror-this-props-navigation-getparam-is-not-a-function-while-passing-parame)
- [When i run this Error: TypeError: navigation.getParam is not a function:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68862475/when-i-run-this-error-typeerror-navigation-getparam-is-not-a-function)

Comment: Your problem is in navigation tree. Your Details screen and App screen are not children of same navigation container like StackNavigator. Can you send navigation file?

Comment: @erkan I attached my friend: `Splash.js` https://jsfiddle.net/L3fjugw9/ `App.js` https://jsfiddle.net/2ma6qsvt/ `AppNavigator.js` https://jsfiddle.net/bogdx2fn/

Comment: Put the code of your stack navigation.

Comment: Your react-navigation version is 6.xx, you must check react-navigation library doc with 6.xx version. According to 6.xx doc you must use "route" props instead of getParam. (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/route-prop). I dont find any doc about getParam function in 6.xx maybe it can be deprecated.

Comment: @erkan Navigation file is not App.js ? I saved it here in the javascript area: https://jsfiddle.net/L3fjugw9/

Comment: @DhavalR Navigation file is not App.js ? I saved it here in the javascript area: https://jsfiddle.net/L3fjugw9/

Comment: because the navigation between components or files is done by the file: `AppNavigator.js` I have already accessed the file: `Detail.js` but creating only a normal text template, when I try to retrieve the news information it already generates that error.

Comment: @erkan If it is obsolete then it would be necessary to change the way in which the parameters are sent and how you receive them, how would this be?

Comment: You can get like that: this.props.route.params.news

Comment: @erkan This has been mentioned to me, you can post an answer using what it should look like and be declared, thanks mate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get route params like that: this.props.route.params.news